# 1D time-dependent Schrödinger equation with absorbing boundary

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-conditions

I'm trying to solve the 1D Schrödinger equation subjected to an absorbing condition using `NDSolve` but cannot seem to set up the absorbing condition...

My problem is defined on the positive $z$-axis for the function $f(z)$. At $z=0$, I put $f(0,t)=0$. At $z=z_{\text{Max}}$, the absorbing condition reads $f'(z_{\text{Max}},t)=-i f(z_{\text{Max}},t)$. At $t=0$, my function is a Gaussian centered at $z=z_{\text{Max}}/2$ (for instance...). So $f(z,0)=\exp[-(z-z_{\text{Max}}/2)^2]$.

My code is

```
NDSolveValue[{I*D[f[z,t],{t}] + D[f[z,t],{z,2}] == NeumanValue[-I*f[z,t],z==zMax], f[z,0]==gz[z], f[0,t]==0}, f, {z,0,zMax}, {t,0,tMax}, , Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
  "MinPoints" -> 100, "MaxPoints" -> 1000, 
  "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}}}]
```

for which I receive an error

```
NDSolveValue::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0.`.
```

I'm quite sure that I do not use `NeumannValue[]` correctly but cannot figure it out...

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `NeumanValue` should be `NeumannValue`.  Also, please specify a value for `zMax` and the function `gz[z]` so that we can attempt to run your code.

Comment: `NeumannValue` does not work with the TensorProductGrid method. Either specify the `NeumannVaue` as a derivative (like shown [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice.html#1529668360)) or use the `FiniteElement` Method.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Indeed, I was able to make my code run using a boundary condition Derivative[1,0][f][zMax,t]==-I*f[zMax,t] instead of using NeumannValue[].

Comment: Can you please post the final working code? Thanks.